# How to properly change component class in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

There are several ways to change a component's class in React.js, but which one is the right one?
I've read that this should be done using the useState hook, but are you sure that changing only the class of an element should result in its re-rendering?
We do not change the structure, we only add a class that will not change the structure of the component, only its appearance. Rendering the whole component again seems wrong in this case. Am I right?

**EDIT**
I have added various examples of components where the class change occurs in different ways. It seems that SuperSimpleCompontent is the most optimal solution, but is it correct?

```js
function UsingRefComponent(){
  const ref = React.useRef();
  return <button ref={ref} onClick={()=>{ref.current.classList.add("new");}}>useRef</button>
}

function UsingStateComponent(){
  const [newClass, setNewClass] = React.useState(null);
  return <button className={newClass} onClick={()=>{setNewClass('new')}}>useState</button>
  
}

function SuperSimpleComponent(){
  return <button onClick={(e)=>{e.preventDefault(); e.target.classList.add("new")}}>simple event target</button>

}
ReactDOM.render(<React.Fragment><UsingRefComponent />vs<UsingStateComponent />vs<SuperSimpleComponent /></React.Fragment>, document.body);
```

```css
button {
  margin:15px;
}
.new {
  background:#000;
  color:#fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Rerendering the whole component is standard. React stores a virtual DOM, which means that whenever part of the app is re-rendered, React only *actually* changes the attributes and renders nodes that have been modified in the real DOM.

Performance in the vast majority of situations is fast enough that the difference is completely unnoticeable. If you're really worried about performance, look into other libraries like Svelte or Solid.js.

Comment: I added some examples, does it matter which way I use?